# Define custom event listener in dart code, not html markup

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In this useful post we can learn how to listen to dispatched custom events by way of inline markup in the template:
[How do I fire a custom event from Polymer Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971511/how-do-i-fire-a-custom-event-from-polymer-dart)
I wonder if it's possible to do the same in the dart-script when custom elements are dynamically created, like this:

```dart
var myElement = new Element.tag('my-element');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you register for custom events in Dart using the new streams API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820756/how-do-you-register-for-custom-events-in-dart-using-the-new-streams-api)

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The referenced question is not about polymer so I added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need for each event handler in your component an `EventStreamProvider` (static)
and a getter for easy access.

```dart
static const EventStreamProvider<CustomEvent> logoutEvent = 
    const EventStreamProvider<CustomEvent>("my-logout");
Stream<CustomEvent> get onLogout =>  MyElement.logoutEvent.forTarget(this);
```

You fire an event like

```dart
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("my-logout", detail: {'someData': 'bla'}));

// Polymer provides a shortcut for this
fire('my-logout', detail: {'someData': 'bla'});
```

You subscribe to this event like

```dart
mySesson.onLogout.listen((e) => doSomething());
```

Comment: Just a little note. I suppose 'mySesson' is a little copy/paste typo. It's supposed to be the dynamically created custom element.

Comment: I just used a name that fit with the example logout event.
That is just the name of a variable referencing a component.